# Handling a null query selector

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my JS I have a query selector as follows:

```
  angular.element(document.querySelector('#formatSearch').blur());
```

I am receiving an error in certain conditions because this element is not present. Is there a way in which I can conditionally execute this blur if the selector does not result in null?

For example:

```
  if (angular.element(document.querySelector('#formatSearch')) !== null) {
    angular.element(document.querySelector('#formatSearch').blur());
  }
```

In this case, I'm still receiving the same error. (null is not an object)

Comment: `if (angular.element(document.querySelector('#formatSearch')) !== null))`

Comment: maybe you should check if `document.querySelector('#formatSearch')` is null

Answer (score 2):

`angular.element()` is in fact `jqLite()` or `jQuery()` which is equivalent of `document.querySelector()`. So why not try this:

`angular.element('#formatSearch').blur();`

**EDIT:** My assumption was proven wrong by [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/2mwv8yuo/). It looks like jqLite does not support the CSS selector to look up elements.

Also, you should be calling `.blur()` on the object returned by `angular.element()`. So change the line to:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#formatSearch')).blur();
```

To solve the error you're getting when the element is not present, change your code to this:

```
if (document.querySelector('#formatSearch')) {  // true only when 'formatSearch' is present
  angular.element(document.querySelector('#formatSearch')).blur();
}
```